# Question about 240V / 5VDC PSU wiring

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi

I am making a Playstation Raspberry Pi project and I am using a new PSU inside the PS1 case to power the Pi. See link to PSU below:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01DDTYMAS/ref=twister_B01DDTYM9E?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

I want to use the original power socket at the rear of the PS1 which is a generic 2 pin (figure of 8) input. I will then solder some wires to the new PSU and then take the 5V output back to the Pi.

My questions are as follows:

1) Is there an issue with the AC+/- inputs on the PSU and the fact that this will change depending on how someone inserts the power cord in the rear 2 pin socket?

2) when the Pi is powered down and the unit is not in use, Should I be worried about heat or general waste of electricity in the PSU whilst it's sitting there connected to the mains?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In countries such as UK and Ireland where polarised plugs are used it is possible to (pretty much) guarantee live (L) and neutral (N) connection in the correct orientation. In the rest of Europe and many parts of the world two-pin plugs are used and can be reversed. Your PS1 also has a reversible mains connector so polartity can not be guaranteed.

> 1) Is there an issue with the AC+/- inputs on the PSU and the fact that this will change depending on how someone inserts the power cord in the rear 2 pin socket?

No.

> 2) when the Pi is powered down and the unit is not in use, Should I be worried about heat or general waste of electricity in the PSU whilst it's sitting there connected to the mains?

It should be fine. Obviously it will waste a couple of watts in standby and this can be eliminated by switching off at the mains.

Make sure you have a suitable fuse in the line to the PSU L terminal if there isn't one built into the PSU.

Comment: If it's a non polarised plug, there's no L and N terminals to choose between :)

Comment: I know. I said that in the first paragraph. In the last paragraph I suggested putting a fuse "*in the line to the PSU L terminal*".

Comment: What, you mean in the power cord?

Comment: No. OP is putting a frame style PSU inside his PS1 case which has a [Type C7](https://www.kenable.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=16190) mains connector. Fuse should go inside the PS1 case between the C7 chassis socket and the PSU L terminal.

Comment: ...which 50% of the time will be connected to Neutral...

Comment: Yup, but that's the convention.

Comment: http://www.powercord9.com/upload/photo/cc4f66d77c62255f13dea562c273068e.jpg
We do have 2 pin plugs that have no earth.

Comment: thanks for help guys - to clarify (if it;s relevant) I am obviously using standard UK 3 pin outlet socket but the power lead is a 2 pin (figure of 8) where it connect to the PS1. This lead has fuse in it in the plug. The PSU says it has some safety feature's like surge and short circuit protection for what that's worth.

Comment: "*I am obviously using standard UK 3 pin outlet ...*". No, that wasn't obvious from your question or your user profile. Surge protection protects the input of the PSU from surges on the mains. Short circuit protection protects the PSU from short circuits or overloads on the output.